# InputQuery Formatting Issues

Tags: forms, user-interface, delphi, inputbox

I'm having trouble with InputQuery/InputBox on Delphi XE2.

The input area is out of place (should be under text).

Is there a way to re-align it before making my own input form?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: That's not how InputQuery works. If you want something different, create a new form and make it look however you want. (You could also make it much easier for your user to input the needed values rather than having them follow some cryptic, hard to understand instructions. My users would shoot me if I did something like you've done here.)

Comment: Totally agree! This program is intended to be used by me. I just wanted to know if I could save some time using built-in functions. I don't need no stinking input validation :)

Comment: Why do you need to give yourself instructions on what format to enter the data if it's only to be used by you? Just change the prompt to *Type here:* and your problem is solved. And how much time does it take to drop a label, an edit, and a couple of buttons on a form? You can even add a class function: `Input := TMyForm.GetTheText;` which could create and show the form and return the input in about five seconds.

Comment: So they are no real world use for InputQuery beside the what is your name type of question? Just curious...

Comment: @ELCouz: basically, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InputQuery()` is not designed to be used in this manner.  The prompt text is meant to be a short label displayed to the left of the text field (similar to `TLabeledEdit`).  It is not designed to display instructions above the prompts, like you are attempting.  This situation would be much better handled by simply creating your own custom Form using whatever controls and layouts you want.  For instance, using `TDateTimePicker` for dates and times, `TCheckBox` or `TRadioGroup` to indicate repeats, etc.

However, that being said, `InputQuery()` is implemented using a custom VCL `TForm`, so it is *technically possible* to accomplish what you are trying to achieve.  You can use the `TScreen.OnActiveFormChange` event to gain access to the Form object when it becomes visible, and then you can manipulate it however you want.  For example:

```
procedure TMyForm.ActiveFormChanged(Sender: TObject);
var
  Form: TCustomForm;
  Prompt: TLabel;
  Edit: TEdit;
  Ctrl: TControl;
  I, J, ButtonTop: Integer;
begin
  Form := Screen.ActiveCustomForm;
  if (Form = nil) or (Form.ClassName <> 'TInputQueryForm') then Exit;

  for I := 0 to Form.ControlCount-1 do
  begin
    Ctrl := Form.Controls[i];
    if Ctrl is TLabel then
    begin
      Prompt := TLabel(Ctrl);
    end
    else if Ctrl is TEdit then
    begin
      Edit := TEdit(Ctrl);
    end;
  end;

  Edit.SetBounds(Prompt.Left, Prompt.Top + Prompt.Height + 5, Prompt.Width, Edit.Height);
  Form.ClientWidth := (Edit.Left * 2) + Edit.Width;
  ButtonTop := Edit.Top + Edit.Height + 15;

  J := 0;
  for I := 0 to Form.ControlCount-1 do
  begin
    Ctrl := Form.Controls[i];
    if Ctrl is TButton then
    begin
      Ctrl.SetBounds(Form.ClientWidth - ((Ctrl.Width + 15) * (2-J)), ButtonTop, Ctrl.Width, Ctrl.Height);
      Form.ClientHeight := Ctrl.Top + Ctrl.Height + 13;
      Inc(J);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyForm.DoSomething;
var
  value: string;
begin
  Screen.OnActiveFormChange := ActiveFormChanged;
  try
    InputQuery('Enter New Schedule', 'Format: <Second> <Minute> <Hour> <Day_of_the_Month> <Month_of_the_Year> <Day_of_the_Week> <Year>.'#10'Use * for repeating cycles. ex: 0 0 7 * * * * (trigger at 7AM everyday)', value);
  finally
    Screen.OnActiveFormChange := nil;
  end;
end;
```

[image]

Alternatively:

```
class procedure TScreenEvents.ActiveFormChanged(Sender: TObject);
var
  Form: TCustomForm;
  Instructions: TLabel;
  Ctrl: TControl;
  I, J, K, Offset: Integer;
begin
  Form := Screen.ActiveCustomForm;
  if (Form = nil) or (Form.ClassName <> 'TInputQueryForm') then Exit;

  for I := 0 to Form.ControlCount-1 do
  begin
    Ctrl := Form.Controls[I];
    if Ctrl is TLabel then
    begin
      Instructions := TLabel.Create(Form);
      Instructions.Parent := Form;
      Instructions.Caption := 'Format: <Second> <Minute> <Hour> <Day_of_the_Month> <Month_of_the_Year> <Day_of_the_Week> <Year>.'#10'Use * for repeating cycles. ex: 0 0 7 * * * * (trigger at 7AM everyday)';
      Instructions.SetBounds(Ctrl.Left, Ctrl.Top, Instructions.Width, Instructions.Height);

      Offset := Instructions.Top + Instructions.Height + 5;
      Form.ClientWidth := Instructions.Width + (Instructions.Left * 2);

      K := 0;
      for J := 0 to Form.ControlCount-1 do
      begin
        Ctrl := Form.Controls[J];
        if Ctrl <> Instructions then
        begin
          Ctrl.Top := Ctrl.Top + Offset;
          if Ctrl is TEdit then
          begin
            Ctrl.Width := (Form.ClientWidth - Ctrl.Left - Instructions.Left);
          end
          else if Ctrl is TButton then
          begin
            Ctrl.Left := (Form.ClientWidth - (Ctrl.Width + 5) * (2-K));
            Inc(K);
          end;
        end;
      end;

      Form.ClientHeight := Form.ClientHeight + Offset;
      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyForm.DoSomething;
var
  value: string;
begin
  Screen.OnActiveFormChange := ActiveFormChanged;
  try
    InputQuery('Enter New Schedule', 'Value', value);
  finally
    Screen.OnActiveFormChange := nil;
  end;
end;
```

[image]